# Keyboard stuck while clicking on textField to get date from DatePickerDialog

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2

I am using DatePickerDialog library to get date picker while clicking on time textField. However, when I click on the Trainer-2 textField which is above the time textField then keyboard appears which is fine but when I click on time textField then the keyboard does not disappear and date picker appears behind it so the page gets stuck.

Below is the code.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

if textField == timeTextField {

self.view.endEditing(true)
self.getTime(textField: textField)

}

}

func getTime(textField: UITextField) {

DispatchQueue.main.async {

            DatePickerDialog().show(title: "DatePicker", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", datePickerMode: .time) {
                (time) -> Void in
                guard let date_time = time else { return }

}
}
```

Below are the images.

1)When click on Trainer-1 textfield, keyboard appears which is fine.

[image: when click on trainer-1 textfield]

2)when click on time textfield to get the datePicker

[image: when click on time textField]

I just want keyboard to disappear when click on time textField to gett he DatePicker.

Thanks.

Comment: why you are not tried with `inputView` for `time textField`

Answer (score 0):

Use this. When you click on timeTextField, keyboard will disappear

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   if textField == timeTextField {
     self.view.endEditing(true)
     self.getTime(textField: textField)
   }
}
```

instead

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't even want to show the keyboard after touching `timeTextField`, you can dismiss it right away in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == timeTextField { 
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.getTime(textField: textField)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: The keyboard doesn't disappear or what do you mean by it doesn't work, please be specific.

Comment: I mean keyboard does not disappear.

Comment: Btw why are you even using a `UITextField`? A `UITextField` is specifically designed to gather text based user input through the keyboard. For your use case a `UILabel` or `UITextView` would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow like..

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //print("While entering the characters this method gets called")

    if(textField == timeTextField){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,
In viewDidload, Set date picker as an input view that text field

`override func viewDidLoad()
{
   timeTextField.inputView = objDataPicker
}`